# Change in the Closure, Interior, and Boundary of a set when the topology is changed

Tags: general-topology

Let $A=(0,1], B=[0,1], C=(0,1)$, and $D=\{0,1\}$. I know that in the usual topology we have
$\operatorname{closure}(A) = B, int(A) = C$ and $\sigma(A)=D$. However, when we consider the set of real numbers as a  topological space where the topology is the power set of the reals, then it is given that $\operatorname{closure}(A) = (0,1], \operatorname{int}(A) = (0,1]$ and $\sigma(A)=\emptyset$. What is the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, since that topology consists of *all* subsets of $\Bbb R$, then, with respect to that topology, *every* set is open. And, since every set is open, every set is closed.

Now, since the closure of a set is the smallest subset that contains it, if a set is closed, then it is equal to its own closure. And, since the interior of a set is the largest of its subsets, if a set is open, then it is equal to its own interior.

Finally, since the boundary of a set $S$ is its closure minus its interior, if a set is both closed and open, then its boundary is the empty set.